# How to predict values using Multiple inputs in Tensor flow

Tags: python, database, numpy, tensorflow, regression

I am relatively new to using Tensor Flow.

I have a data set.

```
    Force    Thickness   Stress    Strain
  30.488816  0.863769   4.325608  4.721202
  11.937097  2.993993  12.916784  1.086236
  25.569493  4.672679   2.168464  9.315900
  18.892368  0.932785   4.535396  0.598124
```

etc I have a 1000 sample data sets for all.

Now i want to use Tensor flow to predict the value of strain and stress when force and thickness is given.

Can anyone please help me to where to get started on this and how to approach this kind of problem, I am really stuck and don;t even know where to start off from.

Comment: There are several ways in which you could predict the strain value. What kind of prediction/fit do you want? Linear, polynomial? In which metric should the distance be measured? Least square?
Do you know how you would do this by hand (i.e. is it actually about programming or about mathematical advice?)

Comment: I am looking for polynomial prediction and distance  Least square.

Comment: Polynomial of what order?